# changed app name by accident, now can't change back

Tags: app-store-connect

I have submitted an update to my app which is waiting for review, and I went in to edit the meta data, changed the title, and saved by accident. Now when I try to change it back to the original name, it says "The App Name you entered has already been used.". Does anyone know how to fix this? (hopefully without having to manually reject the submission).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called App Store Developer Support (408-974-4897) and after about a week and a half they were able to free up my app name so I could use it again.

Answer (score 3):

The solution in [this article](http://hesh.am/2012/01/recovering-a-deleted-app-name-in-itunes-connect/) suggests that you might be able to get it to work by changing the Default Language.

If you're not sure where to set the Default Language, have a look at the [iTunes Connect Developers Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW44).

Comment: Maybe I'll try that, though I didn't even delete it! Thanks though.

Comment: It's just that it sounds like it might be the same problem as a delete. iTunes has a record of that name being used before, so it won't let you use it again - it doesn't know that you're attempting to reuse it for the same app that originally used it.

Comment: Believe your method will work, but I'm just waiting to see from Apple if they'll change it for me before I mark this as correct. Either way, upvoted.